# $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y\mid X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X\mid X+Y)+\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X+Y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Is this equality true for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$? Or maybe we should also assume the same distribution?

Answer (score 4):

The conditional distribution of a random variable $Z$ given $Z=z$ is just the unit mass at $z$.  This has variance $0$. Therefore $\text{Var}(X+Y \mid X+Y) = 0$.
On the other hand, $\text{Var}(X \mid X+Y) \ge 0$; equality means $X+Y$ determines $X$ almost surely.  That can happen, but usually is not the case.  So your equality is not true in general.

Comment: So how can I find $\text{Var}(X|X+Y)$ in terms of $X+Y$?

Comment: @Math122 : Depending on what sort of answer would satisfy you, it would probably depend on the distributions of $X$ and $Y. \qquad$

Comment: $X$ has $N(0,1)$ distribution and $X+Y$ has $N(0,2)$ distribution.